# how to set proxy for pivotal cloud foundry(pcf)?

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

while login to PCF i'm facing below error, can anyone suggest how to set proxy for PCF?

```
C:\Users\girdhars>cf login -a https://api.run.pivotal.io
API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/info: dial tcp: lookup api.run.pivotal.io: no such host
TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, You have to set **HTTP_PROXY** in system variable.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-12/cf-cli/http-proxy.html

Comment: Where in the PDF is the required steps mentioned? Could you please point that out?